# Remmina copy past does not work - Ubunu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, remmina

I search more time in the world wide but I dont find any solution
Before ubuntu 16.04 I had ubuntu 14.04 and remmina copy past work as well
But now on ubuntu 16.04 it does not work
What is problem and How I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Suggested fix is to upgrade

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

according to

- https://www.ithowtoo.com/2017/01/31/ubuntu-16-04-fixing-no-copy-and-paste-into-remmina-rdp-client/
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1439478/comments/22